# How to find boundaries of triple integrals when there are more than 2 conditions on each variable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need to set up the triple integral for the volume of the body given by

$x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$, $x^2+y^2-z^2\geq0$, $y+x\geq 0$, $y\geq 0$ and $z\geq0$. I can probably calculate the volume by splitting up the problem but I also need to find the center of mass which I can't do without setting up a proper triple integral for volume of the body.

So the first inequality gives all points within a sphere with radius 1. The second all points outside a cone. Third I can't explain well but it is a plane that slices the body in half. 4th gives all points above the xz-plane and 5th all points above xy plane.

All together it is the points outside a cone but within the sphere, above the xy plane and covering the angle from $0$ to $3\pi/4$ with respect to the xy-plane.

Edit: I know how to solve set up easier triple integrals where a variable have two conditions. But not where all have more than 2.

Edit: Using geometric arguments the body is given by $0\leq \rho\leq 1$, $\pi/4\leq\phi\leq\pi/2$ and $0\leq\theta\leq\ 3\pi/2$. But how is this shown using the inequalities directly?

Comment: Wait what I can't set up the triple integral with its boundary points.

Comment: Use spherical coordinates $(\rho,\theta,\phi)$ and write the limits for the conditions $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$, $x^2+y^2-z^2\geq0$, and $z\geq0$. The inequalities $y+x≥0$ and  $y\geq 0$ give a further restriction for $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Perform the following change of coordinates:
$$\begin{cases} 
x=\rho \sin \varphi \cos \vartheta\\
y=\rho \sin \varphi \sin \vartheta\\
z=\rho \cos \varphi \\
\end{cases}$$
with $\rho \in [0,+\infty)$, $\vartheta \in [0,2\pi)$ and $\varphi \in [0,\pi]$. Your domain becomes:

$$\begin{cases} 
0 \leq\rho \leq 1\\
\rho^2\sin^2\varphi-\rho^2\cos^2\varphi\ge0\\
\rho \sin \varphi \cos \vartheta +\rho \sin \varphi \sin \vartheta\ge0\\\rho \sin \varphi \sin \vartheta\ge0\\
\rho \cos \varphi\ge0
 \end{cases}$$
Solving it, you get the bounds directly.

Comment: Where does $\rho^2\sin^2\varphi-\rho^2\cos^2\varphi\geq 0$ come from?

Comment: @perpersson the second inequality

Comment: $\rho^2 \sin^2 \varphi \cos^2 \vartheta +\rho^2 \sin^2 \varphi \sin^2 \vartheta -\rho^2 \cos^2 \varphi=\rho^2 \sin^2 \varphi (\cos^2 \vartheta+\sin^2 \vartheta)-\rho^2 \cos^2 \varphi=\rho^2 \sin^2 \varphi-\rho^2 \cos^2 \varphi= $ @perpersson

Comment: @perpersson if the answer is useful, please consider accepting it